# Facebook PHP SDK empty album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a Facebook App that get the user Facebook albums and pictures. I all works fine but if the user has an album with no picture in it my app crash because it can't get an album cover and album pictures count. I've tried to escape the foreach that I use but with no success. It "iterate" only the albums prior to the empty one. Here is the raw code snippet:

```
<?php
$albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums");
foreach ($albums['data'] as $album) {
    $album_id = $album['id'];
    $album_cover = $album['cover_photo'];
    $album_name = $album['name'];
    $album_count = $album['count'];
    $covers = $facebook->api("/" . $album_cover . "");
    $source = $covers['source'];
    ?>
```

Some guidance and suggestions are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test to see if your album has pictures before getting any data:

```
$albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums");
foreach ($albums['data'] as $album) {
  if (0 < $album['count'] {
    $album_id = $album['id'];
    ...
  }
}
```